# animated menu straying in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I am in the middle of writting this new website for my company.

http://www.bestlincs.co.uk/new2/

my issue is that when in chrome, you click any one of the animated menu buttons and then come back its positioned off to the left.

Any ideas why ?? i've tried it in IE and it works fine

Comment: no issues in chrome for me

Comment: I get the error you mention, when I click the "back" button in Chrome. How about sharing some code that you believe is relevant?

Comment: Try removing `margin: auto;` from class .jimgMenu

Comment: @selite if I do that it stays to the left, i need it to stay to the middle

Comment: I think this is more a bug in Chrome than the coding